# How to fetch GlobalObjectId using List Calendar View Graph API call?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I understand the recommended way to uniquely identify an Outlook meeting is to use the `GlobalObjectID` (or `CleanGlobalObjectId`), rather than `iCalUID`. I am struggling to find a way to extract this value when using Microsoft Graph's `CalendarView` endpoint

I've read through this page here, and that is what drives my question - [MSDN Question on iCalUID vs GlobalObjectId](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e1714a15-1ef7-4868-a701-f53c5ceae1ad/ews-api-differences-in-icaluid-returned-when-appointments-are-created-by-office-365-account-vs?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment)

At present, I am using Microsoft Graph's [List CalendarView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) view date range query params, and `$select` and `$filter` OData attributes

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that you should rely on the Event's `id`, I'm not sure where the concern over `iCalUId` stems from. Regardless, `GloablObjectID` [is not a property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event) returned from the Outlook APIs.

There is a preview of [immutable identifiers for Outlook resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id) on the beta endpoint but keep in mind that this is not suitable for production use yet.